# Click button with Watir can't find button

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Trying to test a poll vote with Watir.  Just using a script at the moment, and I can't get the script to find the correct button.

HTML (reformatted slightly for readability)

```
<a href="#" class="btn-poll-short" 
            data-action-url="http://url.com/poll/vote.do" 
            data-svar="svar1" 
            data-type="picture_5569154" 
            data-action="a:1" data-socialpollanswer="Yes" 
            data-pollid="5569154" 
            data-shareanswerpicture=""
            onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.url.com/news/world-news/protective-dad-makes-daughter-wear-5568808#_3&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">

                Yes
</a>
```

My method for the click action:

```
def vote
    browser = Watir::Browser.new
    browser.goto 'http://www.url.com/news/world-news/protective-dad-makes-daughter-wear-5568808'
    sleep 5
    browser.td(:class => 'btn-poll-short').span(:id => 'Yes').click
end
```

Comment: note for future, it is helpful to post HTML that covers anything being used in your code..  in the code above you are trying to work with a table and a span, but your html is for a link, without any context as to how that relates to the table or span in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML, you should try:

```
browser.link(:class => 'btn-poll-short').click
```

or

```
browser.link(:text => 'Yes').click
```

In your `vote` method, you are trying to locate a span within a table cell (instead of a link with a class attribute).